# Can not open Multiple Browser by using selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am new to selenium grid. I want to do testing in parallel mode. I tried as like following. But it won't open the multiple browsers. I don't know what I have done wrongly.

My Code :

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
        driver.navigate().to("http://gmail.com");
    }
```

Selenium Hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role hub
```

Selenium Node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5560 -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstance=3 -maxSession 3
```

Info Prints in Hub :

```
16:38:28.581 INFO - Available nodes: [http://192.168.1.28:5560]
```

16:38:28.581 INFO - Trying to create a new session on node http://192.168.1.28:5560

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ6hz.png)

Comment: Cloud you try this: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5560 -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3

Comment: yes i have tried. Please see the configuration image

Comment: Instead of maxSessions try maxInstances, like this "browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3" (use the comma not the minus)

Comment: I don't think you can open several Firefox instances on the same node at the same time. As I got the concept of Selenium grid, you need 10 nodes if you want to open 10 browsers simultaneously.

Comment: Yes Morvader  i tried with maxInstances=3, Still i can not open multiple browser on single node.

Comment: Hi Kim, As per my study about selenium, we can open multiple instance in the same node. But i don't know actual problem

Comment: Selenium automatically creates 5 Firefox instance, 5 chrome instance and 1 IE on a single node. But if I give the option for selenium, it's not creating as per my option requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this. 
I only did the mistake in the command.

I should used **maxInstance** instead of **maxInstances**

The command should be like this

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5580 -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3 -maxSession=3
```

Answer (score 0):

maxInstance=3 in your command is wrong. It should be 'maxInstances=3'.